# Error Android AVD Opening?

Tags: android

### When i was open my AVD this issue came, If anyone have solution for  this please help me.

[2015-02-26 01:24:44 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:675)
        at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:342)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:521)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:831)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:799)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:759)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:648)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:576)

Comment: you are using multiple instance of IDE ?

Comment: yes..eclipse and Android Studio..

Comment: I think there is no harmful effect due to this error message.It normally comes when we opening multiple instances of IDE

Comment: Completely changed my SDK Location from one dir to another dir.Bt now also  having same issue came..

Comment: k wat i can do for this, please give a solution for this..